# iOS 13.3 Progressive Web App meta tag not working

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, paw

Within the `<head>` of my webpage I have the:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

According to Apple developer, this is all that is needed for the app to launch in “standalone” mode. However, when clicking the bookmark that I had added to home it launches in the default safari rather than its own instance. What’s confusing me is that I copied these tags from another web page that I made last week that does work.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks in advance for any answers and I am more than willing to provide any more of my html file if needed.

Full head:

```
<head>
<title>XXXXXX</title>

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<link rel="icon" href="icon.jpeg">

<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="XXXXXX">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.jpeg">
</head>
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "XXXXXX",
  "short_name": "XXXXXX",
  "description": "Placeholder",
  "lang": "en-GB",
  "start_url": "/index.php",
  "scope": "/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "icon.jpeg",
      "type": "image/jpeg",
    }
  ],
}
```

My webpage does utilise an iframe but I’ve seen other web apps that use this and still function as expected.

Comment: Please can you post the rest of your `<head>` section.

Comment: Please see the full <head>, thank you

Comment: Please can you post your manifest.

Comment: Try putting `"display": "fullscreen"` instead of `"display": "standalone"`.

Comment: I changed it but no difference, the manifest here was copied from my other web app which works and just had the paths changed to match the new directory structure.

Comment: Try adding a `"sizes"` attribute to the `"icons"` section and remove the extra comma at the end of the manifest.

Comment: That works now, after a bit of testing it was that rogue comma at the end. I removed it and added the “sizes” attribute for good measure and it works perfectly now. Thank you

Comment: My pleasure. Now I should probably post that as an answer like it is meant to be ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma at the end of the manifest isn't meant to be there and is causing the manifest to be invalid, so the iPhone ignores the manifest and launches the web app as a normal bookmark.

The end of the manifest should be...

```
    }
  ]
}
```